# Split the string in java with change in alphabets and in groups

Tags: java, string

How to split a string in java with change in alphabetical order.
For example split aaaabb to aaaa & bb.
I tried to sort the string by sort function but i am unable to split alphabets in groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
String str = "aaaaabbb";
String strArray[] = str.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
for(String value : strArray){
    System.out.println(value);
}
```